# element.innerHTML not giving full data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, yui

I'm trying to get the innerHTML of an YUI table element. Whenever I try to do so the innerHTML or .html() (jQuery) doesn't give me full html but only  a part of it. I'm confused why is it happening. I don't think there is some kind of upper bound to the size of html() we can retrieve. Here is my code..

```
    alert(document.getElementById("table").innerHTML);
        console.log($("#table").html());
        $.post("MainPageHTML",
              {
                "data" : $("#table").html()
              },function(result){
                    TCProJSM.newsClicked = false;
                    location.href = result;
              },
              "text"
        );
```

Please help and thanks in adance.

Basically I want to save the state of my current page(means all the selections, maps etc on it) while I'm migrating away from it to another page, so when I comeback to this page I just have to repaint the page with my saved stuff. For that I'm doing .html() for the elements required and posting the data to server to be saved. But as I said above I'm getting incomplete data (only few lines from the beginning) for every element I want to save it's state for. 
Is there any thing else I can try apart from HTML to get the data which can be repainted when I visit the page again ??

Comment: We would need to see an example demonstrating your issue. There isn't enough info at the moment.

Comment: What exactly is missing, the end, the beginning, the outer wrap (if so use outerHTML) etc.

Comment: Are you using a YUI DataTable? If so, which version? Are you using the scrollable table?

Answer (score 0):

try to use .html() in jQuery.It will give the whole html.

Comment: But it's written in the question that .html() isn't working for him

Answer (score -1):

innerHTML can't be applied for several DOM elements, such as table, tr or select, instead of it should be used childNodes or something similar.

In your situation it will be better to create some json file based on #table data and post exactly it.